# How to determine the greatest value in a collection of items?

Tags: c#, linq

Using the following simple Item class:

```
class Item
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

And this list of items:

```
var items = new List<Item>();

items.Add( new Item() { Value = 1 } );
items.Add( new Item() { Value = 2 } );
items.Add( new Item() { Value = 3 } );
```

How to tell the greatest value in all items?

How to determine which Item in the list has the greatest value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using LINQ

```
items.Max(v => v.Value)
```

Items containing greatest value

```
var max = items.Max(v => v.Value);
var x = items.Where(v => v.Value == max);
```

However, MaxBy extension method suggested by devdigital will iterate the collection only once

Answer (score 2):

> And how to directly tell the greatest value in all items?

You can use the `Max` standard query operator:

```
var maxValue = items.Max(i => i.Value);
```

> How to determine which Item in the list has the greatest value?

Check out [morelinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) for the `MaxBy` extension

Answer (score 1):

Enumerable.max:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.max.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ItemEvaluator
{
    public int Highest { get { return highest; } }
    public int Lowest { get { return lowest; } }

    public void Add(Item item)
    {
        highest = item.Value > highest ? item.Value : highest;
        lowest = item.Value < lowest ? item.Value : lowest;
        items.Add(items);
    }

    private List<int> items = new List<int>();
    private int lowest;
    private int highest;
}

public class Item
{
    public int Value { get; set; }  
}
```